# sed for a string in only 1 line

Tags: linux, bash, sed

What I want to do here is locate any file that contains a specific string in a specific line, and remove said line, not just the string.

What I have is something along the lines of this:

```
find / -type f -name '*.foo' -exec sed '1/stringtodetect/d' {} \;
```

However this will remove everything BETWEEN line 1 and the string. given that sed argument. `(sed '1,/stringtodetect/d' "$file")`

Lets say I have a .php file, and I'm looking for the string 'gotcha'.
I only want to edit the file if it has the string in the FIRST line of the file, like so:

gotcha with this.

1. gotcha
2. useful text
3. more text
4. dont delete me

If I ran the script, I'd want the contents of the same file to appear as such:

1. List item
2. List item
3. dont delete me

Any tips?

Comment: Why don't you just get rid of the `1,` from the start?

Comment: When you say "in a specific line" - do you mean there's some specific line number you need to find the string on or do you mean something else? Edit your question to show sample input and expected output, and include lines that have occurrences of the string that you do not want to delete if that can happen.

Comment: yeah, specifically I want to remove the first line of any file ending in .php, so long as it contains a specific string IN that first line.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the following *range* address for the delete command:

```
1,/stringtodelete/
```

This means all lines from line `1` until the first occurrence of `stringtodelete`.

Furthermore, you need not (and should not!) iterate over the results from `find`. `find` has the `-exec` option for that. It executes a command for each file which has been found, passing the filename as an argument.

It should be:

```
find / -type f -name '*.foo' -exec sed '/stringtodetect/d' {} \;
```

Test the command first. Once you are sure it works, use `sed -i` to modify the files *in place*. If you want a backup you can use `sed -i.backup` (for example). To remove the backups once you are sure you can use find again:

```
find / -type -name '*.foo.backup' -delete
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a sed script that will skip any line **by number** that is not the one you are interested in, and only for the line you are interested in delete the line if it matches.

```
sed -e1bt -eb -e:t -e/string/d < $file
```

`-e1bt` = for line 1, branch to label "t"

`-eb` = branch unconditionally to the end of the script (at which point it will print the line).

`-e:t` = define label "t"

`-e/string/d` = delete the line if it contains "string" - this instruction will only be reached if the unconditional branch to the end of the script was NOT taken, i.e. if the line number branch WAS taken.

Comment: Brilliant. that actually cleared up some misconceptions of sed I had. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that it is matching parts of a string. 
If you try exact match, it might help. 
Also, remove the 1, at the beginning or replace it with 0,

```
 sed '/<stringtodetect>/d' "$file";
```

Answer (score 0):

sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, that is all. For anything else just use awk for simplicity, clarity, robustness, portability and all of the other desirable attributes of software:

```
awk '!(NR==1 && /stringtodetect/)' file
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close. I think what you're looking for is: `sed '1{/gotcha/d;}'`